# Android cubic carousel view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, 3d, android-viewpager, carousel

I want to add cubic carousel view in my application. To achieve this,I referred [This fragment animation library](https://github.com/kakajika/FragmentAnimations). but it is for fragments not for viewpager or/ recyclerview. So is there any way to achive the same cubic effect.for recyclerview or viewpager?

More details : In my application, I need to read json file which reads product and sub-product when user moves vertically, product will be changed and when user change horizontally, sub product will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this view pager transform library. Visit https://github.com/geftimov/android-viewpager-transformers or you can create your custom cubic viewpager transform like below. It will reduce apk size.

```
public class CubeTransformer extends BaseTransformer {

@Override
protected void onTransform(View view, float position) {
    view.setPivotX(position < 0f ? view.getWidth() : 0f);
    view.setPivotY(view.getHeight() * 0.5f);
    view.setRotationY(90f * position);
}

@Override
public boolean isPagingEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

}

Then add it to your view pager.

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
pager.setPageTransformer(true, new CubeTransformer());
```

That'all.

Comment: provide code snippet link only answers are not good. links can be changed in future